# Error in the code after loading a library in an R code

Tags: errors, r, compilation-error, knitr, tinytex

I have been writing a code in RStudio and using TinyTex to compile my pdf. I wrote the following code in an RSweave file in RStudio:

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{boxy}[1]{colback=green!5!white, colframe=green!75!black, title={#1}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=astral,
    filecolor=astral,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=astral
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\makeatletter
\title{\textbf{\underline{Assignment 2}}}\let\thetitle\@title
\author{Devansh Kamra}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{boxy}{Question No. 1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Run \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|. What do you see?
    \item How many rows are in \verb|mpg|? How many columns?
    \item What does the \verb|drv| variable describe? Read the help for \verb|?mpg| to find out.
    \item Make a scatterplot of \verb|hwy| vs \verb|cyl|.
    \item What happens if you make a scatterplot of class vs drv? Why is the plot not useful?
  \end{enumerate}
\end{boxy}

\section*{\underline{Solution:}}
  \subsection*{\underline{Part 1}}
    Running \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|:
    <<>>=
    ggplot(data = mpg)
    @
    We can easily see that \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)| gives us an empty plane to plot the data on.

\end{document}
```

It gives me this output pdf:
[image]

It says it couldn't find function `ggplot`, which is completely understandable as I didn't load `library("tidyverse")` yet. but it is compiling the pdf, by which I assume there is no LaTeX error as such. Now I simply add `library("tidyverse")` to the previous code:

```
%%same code before
Running \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|:
    <<>>=
    library("tidyverse")
    ggplot(data = mpg)
    @
%%same code after
```

But now I'm getting following errors after compiling and it doesn't produce a pdf.

```
Loading required package: knitr


processing file: assign2.Rnw
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ indent: chr "    "

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: assign2.tex

[1] "assign2.tex"
Compiling document with tinytex ... ! Undefined control sequence.
\f@nch@orh ->\theauthor 
                        \strut 
l.132 \end{document}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile D:/hp/Desktop/assign2.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See assign2.log for more info.
Execution halted
failed

Bad Box: pgf.sty:120: Overfull \hbox (32.5757pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 120--121
Bad Box: pgf.sty:124: Overfull \hbox (68.61136pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 124--124
Bad Box: pgf.sty:128: Overfull \hbox (17.62482pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 128--131
Error: pgf.sty:132: Undefined control sequence.
Error: pgf.sty:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Now I might be wrong about this, but overfull \hbox errors are generally LaTeX errors, and if they are, then why didn't they show before loading `library("tidyverse")`? Kindly help me out rectify these errors, and I apologize if this is trivial, for I am new to R.

***THANK YOU***

**EDIT:** The code gives me a perfectly compiled pdf once I remove the following chunk:

```
%%same code before
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
%%same code after
```

This apparently means that I am unable to use package `fancyhdr` in my code. Why is that, and is there any possible way I can resolve the issue so that I am able to use the package?

**EDIT 2:** The error was in the following chunk:

```
<<>>=
\makeatletter
\title{\textbf{\underline{Assignment 2}}}\let\thetitle\@title
\author{Devansh Kamra}
\makeatother
@
```

In the above chunk, `\let\theauthor\@author` is missing. Once you add that, it compiles the pdf well.

Comment: Two questions. // 1) Does this problem depend on compile settings of your Latex tool? // 2) Can you make it run by deleting or commenting out lines and parts temporarily to localize problems?

Comment: @MS-SPO I'm not sure if it depends on that, and if it does, I'm not aware as how to rectify it. And as for deleting lines and running, it does not produce any pdf after deletion of any line and gives the same errors.

Comment: unrelated to the question but the class option is `12pt` not `12 pt` the version with a space just works by accident (as does `1 2 p t`)

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks and observations, no solution. I put it here as it's almost impossible to include in comments. No discussion intended, see rules of this place.

1. If I copy your initial code (with the wrong [12 pt]) I get this compile, which obviously DIFFERS from yours; it just warns about inputenc:
   [image]
2. Adding your R-related code, doesen't really change anything:
   [image]
3. I'm using MikTex offline. How do you compile Latex?
4. I don't really see at the moment, how R-code is executed and its result included during a Latex compile. Usually you'd use a dedicated package like this (symbolic one) `\usepackage{someR-Magic}` ... but I don't see any in your preamble. (If you haven't yet, check here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r )
5. From your last observation, discarding the fancyheader related code, there is indication that you have interaction. Both wanted interaction via Tidyverse (whatever that is) AND unwanted ineraction (well your results and mine // variability // non-stability).
6. Take my deletion idea a step further:

- split your code into half (more or less)
- compile with one half, and with the complementary other
- repeat stepwise, focusing on that "half" with compile errors (might need investigating both ...)
- this brings you pretty fast to those lines of code, which impose some kind of problem

7. Your assumption "Latex code is fine, at least good enough", may not hold.
8. I wonder what might be the reason to execute R-code during a Latex-compile. Usually you outsource this step, and create drawings separately. This way you separate problems (like may be arise here) and you simply include graphic files, best in .eps format.

Answer (score 0):

Two corrections are required:

1. Don't indent the code chunk that starts with `<<>>=`. The parser won't find it. To get started on code chunks, have a look at the `stationery` package on CRAN: [stationery: Working Examples for Reproducible Research Documents](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stationery/).
2. You need to tell `R` where to get your `ggplot` function call from. Either write `library(ggplot2)` or `ggplot2::ggplot(data=mpg)`.

Compile in `RStudio`, or the `R` plug-in for `WinEdt` is another option, which is also on CRAN: [RWinEdt: R Interface to 'WinEdt'](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWinEdt/index.html)

[image]

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{boxy}[1]{colback=green!5!white, colframe=green!75!black, title={#1}}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=astral,
    filecolor=astral,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=astral
}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\makeatletter
\title{\textbf{\underline{Assignment 2}}}\let\thetitle\@title
\author{Devansh Kamra}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{boxy}{Question No. 1}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Run \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|. What do you see?
    \item How many rows are in \verb|mpg|? How many columns?
    \item What does the \verb|drv| variable describe? Read the help for \verb|?mpg| to find out.
    \item Make a scatterplot of \verb|hwy| vs \verb|cyl|.
    \item What happens if you make a scatterplot of class vs drv? Why is the plot not useful?
  \end{enumerate}
\end{boxy}

\clearpage

\section*{\underline{Solution:}}
  \subsection*{\underline{Part 1}}
    Running \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)|:
    
<<ggplot, out.width="50%", fig.align = "center">>=
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mpg)
@
    
We can easily see that \verb|ggplot(data = mpg)| gives us an empty plane to plot the data on.

\subsection*{\underline{Part 2}}

\texttt{mpg} has \Sexpr{nrow(mpg)} rows and \Sexpr{ncol(mpg)} columns.

\end{document}
```